# Cursor.getColumnIndex() retorna -1

Tags: android, select, sqlite

Estou tentando realizar um *select* no banco de dados do *Android*, mas sempre que tento, acaba gerando erro. Ao realizar o *debug* descobrir que umas das colunas, ao realizar o `getColumnIndex()` está me retornando `-1`, causando erro na aplicação.

Abaixo estar a tabela do banco, o contrato e o *select* para tentar identificar o motivo disso ocorrer. Já estou completamente sem ideias de qual seria o motivo.

***Select* realizado na tabela:**

```
 String[] projection = {
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry._ID,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_NOME,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ICONE,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TAG,

            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ENDERECO,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_BAIRRO,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CIDADE,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ESTADO,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LAT,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LANG,

            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TELEFONE,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_WHATSSAPP,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_FACE,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_INSTAGRAM,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TWITER,
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_YOUTUBE,

            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIA__ID
    };
data = new CursorLoader(getContext(), empresaUri, projection, null, null, null);
if(data.moveToFirst()){
        int iconeIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ICONE);
        int empresaIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_NOME);
        int tagIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TAG);
        int descicaoIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_DESC); //coluna onde o retorno é -1
        int enderecoIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ENDERECO);
        int bairroIndex = data.getColumnIndex(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_BAIRRO);


        String empresa = data.getString(empresaIndex);
        String tag = data.getString(tagIndex);
        String descicao = data.getString(descicaoIndex);
        String endereco = data.getString(enderecoIndex);

Inserção do banco de dados:
ContentValues valuesCategoria = new ContentValues();
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry._ID, empresa.getId());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_NOME, empresa.getNome());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ICONE, empresa.getIcone());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TAG, empresa.getTag());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_DESC, empresa.getMsg());


            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ENDERECO, empresa.getEndereco().getEndereco());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_BAIRRO, empresa.getEndereco().getBairro());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CIDADE, empresa.getEndereco().getCidade());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ESTADO, empresa.getEndereco().getEstado());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LAT, empresa.getEndereco().getLatLng().latitude);
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LANG, empresa.getEndereco().getLatLng().longitude);

            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TELEFONE, empresa.getRedes().getTelefone());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_WHATSSAPP, empresa.getRedes().getWhatsapp());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL, empresa.getRedes().getEmail());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_FACE, empresa.getRedes().getFace());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_INSTAGRAM, empresa.getRedes().getInsta());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TWITER, empresa.getRedes().getTwiter());
            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_YOUTUBE, empresa.getRedes().getYoutube());

            valuesCategoria.put(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIA__ID, empresa.getCategoria().getId());


            int updateEmpresa = context.getContentResolver().update(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.buildUriForBelem(empresa.getId()), valuesCategoria, null, null);

            Log.d("UpdateCategoria", String.valueOf(updateEmpresa));

            if (updateEmpresa == 0) {
                context.getContentResolver().insert(BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.CONTENT_URI, valuesCategoria);

            }
```

**Banco de dados:**

```
final String TABELA_EMPRESA ="CREATE TABLE " +BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.TABLE_NAME +"(" +
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry._ID +                    CREATE_ID               +
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_NOME +            CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT      +
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_DESC +            CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT      +
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ICONE+            CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT      +
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TAG +             CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT      +


            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ENDERECO+        CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_BAIRRO+          CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CIDADE+          CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_ESTADO+          CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LAT+             " REAL , "+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_LANG+            " REAL , "+

            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TELEFONE+           CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_WHATSSAPP+          CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_EMAIL+              CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_FACE+               CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_INSTAGRAM+          CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_TWITER+             CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_YOUTUBE+            CREATE_COLUMN_TEXT+
            BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIA__ID+    CREATE_COLUMN_INTEGER   +

            "FOREIGN KEY("+BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_CATEGORIA__ID+")" +
            " REFERENCES "+BelemContract.CategoriaEntry.TABLE_NAME+
            "("+BelemContract.CategoriaEntry._ID+") "+

            ");";
```

**Contrato do banco:**

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Empresa";

    public static final String _ID =                    "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NOME =            "nome";
    public static final String COLUMN_ICONE =           "icone";
    public static final String COLUMN_TAG =             "tag";
    public static final String COLUMN_DESC =            "descricao";

    public static final String COLUMN_ENDERECO =        "endereco";
    public static final String COLUMN_BAIRRO =          "bairro";
    public static final String COLUMN_CIDADE =          "cidade";
    public static final String COLUMN_ESTADO =          "estado";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT =             "lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_LANG =            "lang";

    public static final String COLUMN_TELEFONE =        "telefone";
    public static final String COLUMN_WHATSSAPP =       "whatsapp";
    public static final String COLUMN_FACE =            "face";
    public static final String COLUMN_INSTAGRAM =       "instagram";
    public static final String COLUMN_TWITER =          "twiter";
    public static final String COLUMN_YOUTUBE =         "youtube";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL =           "email";

    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORIA__ID =   "Categoria__id";
```

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código da query.

Comment: Era exatamente ai onde estava o problema, obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: Era o que eu esperava: a query não retorna essa coluna.

Comment: Acredito que só faltou definir `BelemContract.EmpresaEntry.COLUMN_DESC` dentro de `String[] projection = { ... };`